# How to traffic split/load balance with multiple gae application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, load-balancing

for example, i have 5 gae application provide the same restful service(do not worry the data problem), how can split the request evenly to 5 app with same domain name?

what is the most quickest and simple wait to do the load balance?

I am using java with gae and own a domain I do not own any real machine server.

Comment: Sounds like a massive TOS violation.

Comment: plz just treat it as a academic study >0<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't is the simple answer. What you are trying to do is **exactly what GAE does for you** and is the whole point of GAE. There is simply no point and it's also a TOS violation as Wooble points out (I don't hav a reference to hand, but it's been asked before).

So bite the bullet, enable billing and let GAE do your load balancing for you. Which essentially means it'll spin up a new instance when your current instances take more then ~1s to respond.